# Transforming an object value in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

What is the best way to transform the following array

```
           [{
                "language":"de",
                "title": "test DE",
                "content": "Context DE Test",
                "summary": "Cummary DE test",
            }]
```

to the following format.

```
            [{
                "language": { "name": "de" },
                "title": "test DE",
                "content": "Context DE Test",
                "summary": "Cummary DE test",
            }]
```

I need to change the structure of the language key in the object.

Comment: Yes, it can be done using map(). What have you tried? Do you know about spread syntax: `...`? (also, bonus points for not using the word JSON ;)

Comment: To answer your question: Yes. Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I think this should do it?

```
languages.map(({ language, ...rest }) => ({
  language: { name: language },
  ...rest,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let array1 = [{
  "language": "fr",
  "title": "test FR",
  "content": "Context fr Test",
  "summary": "Cummary fr test",
},
{
  "language": "de",
  "title": "test DE",
  "content": "Context DE Test",
  "summary": "Cummary DE test",
}]
let res = array1.map((value, index) => {
  return { ...value, language: { name: value.language } }
})
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr =    [{
                "language": "fr",
                "title": "test FR",
                "content": "Context fr Test",
                "summary": "Cummary fr test",
            },
            {
                "language":"de",
                "title": "test DE",
                "content": "Context DE Test",
                "summary": "Cummary DE test",
            }];

const newObj = arr.map( obj => {...obj , language : {name : obj.language}});

console.log(newObj)
```

With map and the spread operator, like you said.